# Problem separating .h and .cpp file

Tags: c++

I am writing a class and need to separate the declarations from the implementation, but I keep receiving "undefined reference" errors when compiling and linking my test program.  It works fine when I include the implementation in the .h file, so I believe I am doing something wrong in there.  I just can't figure out what.

**Huge_Integer.h**

```
#ifndef HUGE_INTEGER_H
#define HUGE_INTEGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Huge_Integer
{
   public:
      Huge_Integer();
      Huge_Integer(string);
      void input();
      string output();
      void add(Huge_Integer);
      void subtract(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_equal_to(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_not_equal_to(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_greater_than(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_less_than(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_greater_than_or_equal_to(Huge_Integer);
      bool is_less_than_or_equal_to(Huge_Integer);
   private:
      vector<int> value;
};

#endif
```

**Huge_Integer.cpp**

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

#include "Huge_Integer.h"

using namespace std;

// all stubs for now...

Huge_Integer::Huge_Integer()
{
   cout << "object created\n";
}

Huge_Integer::Huge_Integer(string s)
{
   cout << "object created\n";
}

//etc...
```

It also works if I put `#include "Huge_Integer.cpp"` in my test file, but I shouldn't have to do that, right?

I am using MinGW.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added stubs from my .cpp file

Comment: Show the exact error message and tell us how you're compiling it. Also, what do you think of operator overloading?

Comment: Give an example how you define functions in C++ file.

Comment: **Never** put `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: Never `#include "Huge_Integer.cpp"` (or any .cpp) for that matter in your header file - this breaks **encapsulation**. The only time this is "acceptable" is when you need it when using `template`'s.

Comment: I am using JGrasp and the Compile and Link option.  Here is the error:

Huge_Integer_Test.cpp:16: undefined reference to  Huge_Integer::Huge_Integer()
Huge_Integer_Test.cpp:17: undefined reference to Huge_Integer::output()
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Perhaps you have written a prototype for those two functions but didn't write their definitions... just a guess!

Comment: Are you linking Huge_Integer.o together with Huge_Integer_Test.o ?

Comment: Did you implement the functions with the right namespace? `Huge_Integer::Huge_Integer() { /*Impl*/ }`

Comment: Delnan, these are for an assignment and all the functions were defined by my teacher.  I am aware of overloading, but can you please elaborate what you were referring to?

Comment: I believe I am linking them together.  Does Compile and Link do that?

Comment: It looks You don't compile Your class (the Huge_Integer.cpp file).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a linking issue.
What that means is that you have to compile your class first -- this will create a compiled object file.
Then compile the main program while passing in this compiled version of the class.

Like this:

```
g++ -c huge_integer.cpp
g++ main.cpp huge_integer.o
```

Substitute your mingw command for g++ if it is different.

Answer (score -1):

Not related to linking, but you are referring to `Huge_Integer` inside the class declaration itself.

At least with g++, you should add a forward declaration before so that `Huge_Integer` has meaning inside the class declaration thus:

```
class Huge_Integer;   // forward declaration

class Huge_Integer {
  Huge_Integer();
  // etc...
  void add(Huge_Integer);
```

Note: I don´t have comment privileges, so I had to type in the answer box.

Comment: This is not at all required. Member functions of a class have access to the full definition when being parsed- how else could they access member functions and variables which were not defined before them if they are defined inline?